# Why do my QlikSense charts show blank unless I select values explicitly

Tags: qliksense

I'm not sure if something changed in an update or what. This didn't use to happen. I'm in the newest version.

All the charts I create show blank unless I explicitly select values from selections pane or in a filter pane. Shouldn't the default show all data until I activate a filter by selection? I know that there's an option to select everything from a selection on open, but I can't seem to find how to disable what's happening now as the default. This is not just on a single chart here and there. It's on anything I create. And it happens regardless of extension or internal charts. Qlik Sense included vs VizLib, etc.

You can see no filter is created, yet no data. And the setting that would do this in a single chart isn't engaged. And to be clear, I haven't messed with any settings in the chart beside placing the Dimension and Measure fields... very simple.

```
ASSIGNEE_F04
Count(Distinct TASK_ID_F04)
```

I've tried playing with any settings within the chart itself, but nothing works. Is there some kind of global defaults setting that I can change somewhere?

[image]

And if I force selections...

[image]

Comment: Also having this issue, have you had any luck so far?

Comment: Are you using the Loosen Table statement in your script?

Comment: I take it you are referring to the script in the 'Data load editor'? I took a look but did not see any reference to Loosen Table in the script.

Comment: Yes, that was part of the issue for me. Some of the synthetic keys that were being created were creating a sort of Cartesian effect, so I added the Loosen Table script thinking that it would solve the issue. It stopped the relationships but caused other issues. After the data load is done, go to the data manager, sync tables, and load from there. That may fix the problem. That's something else I've seen.